# Angular2: Read local json file on server side

Tags: json, angular, typescript

My app should read a config.json file that is supplied by the customer to their server. To save an HTTP request, I want to do this directly on server side.

I know I could put it into /assets and then request it from client side, but this requires an unnecessary HTTP request, and also exposes the config.json file.

I could read the file on server side in typescript with "import" or "require", but with "ng build" the config.json file disappears in the dist and gets incorporated into main.bundle.js. However, I don't have this file at compile time; the customer should be able to add it to their installation.

In angular code, I want to show information like {{config.version}}.

Is there any way to do this in Angular? Or do I need to somehow extend the index.html with PHP code? Using PHP, how could I pass the config object to the angular code?

Answer (score 0):

use `http` to read the json file:

```
config: Observable<any>;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.config = this.http.get('config.json');
}
```

HTML

```
{{ (config | async).version }}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want to do.